# gosu will not play .wav file when running from ruby, but will play in irb

Tags: ruby, audio

The .wav file doesn't play this way:

```
$ ruby -e "require 'gosu'
> Gosu::Sample.new( Gosu::Window.new( 100, 100, false ), 'car_sounds/01.wav' ).play"
```

But when I run the same code from irb, the .wav file does play.

```
$ irb
1.9.3p448 :001 > require 'gosu'
 => true
1.9.3p448 :002 > Gosu::Sample.new( Gosu::Window.new( 100, 100, false ), 'car_sounds/01.wav' ).play
 => #<Gosu::SampleInstance:0x0000000166bba0>
```

I also ran the same code from ruby with a `use rubygems` statement; this didn't help.

The version of ruby is ruby 1.9.3p448.